# How to Update the installed Window Application (Creating Patches)

Tags: deployment, setup-project, setup-deployment, setuptools, patch

i have requirement. i have created the window application and i have created the setup of that application that has been installed to client machine.

Now the requirement is that if i will do the further modification to the project the client not need to install whole application again instead client only need to install Update of new version. like using Patches or something. How can i do this is there and tool in VS from which we can create the update patches or something.

Please Help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem...using ClickOne Setup of VS. i publish the win form to a specific URl and each time when application launchs its check the Upgraded version if available it install and run.

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, but they depend on which installer you used in the first place.

It is very easy with Inno Setup, as (if the file items are configured correctly) InnoSetup will detect that the application is already installed and only copy modified files, even though you publish the entire setup. This will be automatic.

If you used the built-in Visual Studio setup project, it is also possible, but you must set a different "upgrade id" in the setup properties. I haven't worked much with this, yet.

A third option is using Windows Installer XML (WIX), which is able to generate patch installers, but I haven't worked much with WIX yet.

One last option would be to write something yourself that is able to exchange old files against new files, but you'd have to keep UAC in mind for newer Windows versions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..

I want that that there must not the user interaction for update window application automatically ( "force" the users to always use the latest version). Do you have any idea how to create patch using Visual Studio setup project because my new setup was created using Visual Studio setup project.

Comment: Haven't read all of it, but a quick Google showed me this article: http://murrayon.net/2008/03/creating-patch-installers.html

Comment: I have solved the problem...using ClickOne Setup of VS. i publish the win form to a specific URl and each time when application launchs its check the Upgraded version if available it install and run.

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm

Comment: Yes, ClickOnce is a very handy technology. I didn't mention it as you asked for setup solutions. Please note, however, that ClickOnce installs on a per-user-basis. Also, if you use user settings, you have to make sure to have the application update the settings if necessary. Otherwise your users will have to configure the application from scratch after every update. (http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2005/12/09/246.aspx)